# Get Packete url using Pcap.Net

Tags: c#, .net, https, pcap, pcap.net

I need to find a way to get all `HTTPS` packet from `PCAP file`

Is it Ok if i'll take only TCp packets with port 443 (source or destination) or i need to check somewhere inside the packet (where ?) the URL ?

Comment: From https you will only see ssl packets with TLS protocol on top of it. Since the traffic is encrypted you cannot see whats inside it. Could be http, UDP or the plain text file of Edward Snowdens leaked NSA documents. If you get the server certificate you can decrypt the traffic but usually you wont get it.

Comment: Any suggestions how only to recognize this SSL packet ? (i just want to know how can i distinguished between SSL and regular traffic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, TCP port 443 would be good enough to get all HTTPS packets for most applications.